# WHERE clause to filter times that are under an hour

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
    name,
    start_time,
    TIME(cancelled_date) AS cancelled_time,
    TIMEDIFF(start_time, TIME(cancelled_date)) AS difference
FROM
    bookings
```

I'm trying to get from the database a list of bookings which were cancelled with less than an hour's notice. The start time and the cancellation times are both in TIME format, I know a timestamp would have made this easier. So above I've calculated the time difference between the two values and now need to add a WHERE clause to restrict it to only those records that have a difference of under 1:00:00. Obviously this isn't a number, it's a time, so a simple bit of maths won't do it.

- start_time is a TIME
- cancelled_date is a DATETIME but I'm converting it to TIME in the query to then calculate cancelled_time and difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `having difference<time('1:00')`

Answer (score 2):

I would be inclined to do this by adding and hour to the notice, something like this:

```
WHERE start_time > date_add(cancelled_date, interval 1 hour)
```

I can't quite tell what the right logic is from the question, because your column names don't match the description.

In this case, so a subtraction or doing the comparison are similar performance wise.  But, if you had a constant instead of `cancelled_date`, then there is a difference.  The following:

```
WHERE start_time < date_add(now(), interval -1 hour)
```

Allows the engine to use an index on `start_time`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. That doesn't quite work for me but I think it's certainly along the right lines. I've edited the question to make the formats a bit clearer.

Comment: @MKC . . . How do you know what the difference is, if one is a time and the other a date?  Do you assume they happened on the same date?